# Calculate the average of columns, then remove the columns using Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a data set in a Google Spreadsheet with each column representing a year. The data I want from this spreadsheet is the average over five years, so I create a column for each five year interval containing the average (calculated with =AVERAGE(B2:F2) for the second row and first interval). Now I do not want the columns with specific years when I create a .csv file of the data and use it in my program, but only the columns containing the average. If I remove those columns that I don't want I will get an error saying that elements are missing.

Is there a way, in Google Spreadsheet, to "save" the calculated average (or any function for that matter) in the column so that it only contains a single numeric value and has no dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, you could highlight all the cells with the averages, copy and paste special - values.  that would remove all the formulas you have in those cells but would keep the values when you delete the data columns.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!